# Facebook API Windows Phone using CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

When following the blog outlining the use of the facebook API under codenameoOne, it only stated how to do this under iOS and Android. Is it possible to use the facebook functionality under Windows Phone? I haven't seen the "Bundle ID" on the Windows Phone setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two ways to connect to Facebook: Native and Lightweight.

On Windows Phone only the lightweight mode is supported at the moment, Facebook officially deprecated that method even though it provided no alternative for quite a few platforms. E.g. they don't seem to have an official Windows Phone SDK.

Our lightweight login (demonstrated in the FacebookDemo app) allows you to login using the web UI which should work everywhere. You should use it as a fallback when the facebook connect API indicates that it is unsupported.